# Using enumerate loop to update a list of dicts in python not working as expected

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries in python.
I want to update one key:value pair for all the dicts with unique values but instead all of them are getting the same value.

Here's my code:

```
num_cntxts=4
pkt_eop   =[{'type' : 'eop', 'number':1}]
pkt_eop_pattern = pkt_eop*num_cntxts

#I want to add a 'cntxt' key to each of the 4 dicts
#which should have the value as the list position

for i,pkt_eop_inst in enumerate(pkt_eop_pattern):
   print i,pkt_eop_inst
   pkt_eop_inst['cntxt']=i

>0 {'cntxt': 0, 'type': 'eop', 'number': 1}
1 {'cntxt': 2, 'type': 'eop', 'number': 1}
2 {'cntxt': 4, 'type': 'eop', 'number': 1}
3 {'cntxt': 6, 'type': 'eop', 'number': 1}

The print statement shows the individual dict elements but the result is: 

>pkt_eop_pattern
'[{'cntxt': 6, 'type': 'eop', 'number': 1}, {'cntxt': 6, 'type': 'eop', 'number': 1}, {'cntxt': 6, 'type': 'eop', 'number': 1}, {'cntxt': 6, 'type': 'eop', 'number': 1}]
```

What I wanted was the pkt_eop_pattern to match the print output:

```
>pkt_eop_pattern
'[{'cntxt': 0, 'type': 'eop', 'number': 1}, {'cntxt': 2, 'type': 'eop', 'number': 1}, {'cntxt': 4, 'type': 'eop', 'number': 1}, {'cntxt': 6, 'type': 'eop', 'number': 1}]
```

When I iterate over the list, I expected to get a pointer to each dict.
However, that is not the case since all elements are taking the value of the last iteration.

Answer (score 1):

What happens when you do

```
pkt_eop_pattern = pkt_eop*num_cntxts
```

is that you get a list with `num_cntxts` references to the *same* dictionary.

You will need to `copy` the dictionary. Luckily, since you're iterating over it (and list extension is relatively lightweight in python):

```
num_cntxts=4
pkt_eop   =[{'type' : 'eop', 'number':1}]

#I want to add a 'cntxt' key to each of the 4 dicts
#which should have the value as the list position

for i in xrange(num_cntxts):
   my_copy = pkt_eop.copy()
   pkt_eop_pattern.append(my_copy)
   my_copy['cntxt'] = i
```

Comment: Thanks, didnt realize I was getting the references to the same dictionary. This explains it!